# Passing pointer to a member of a struct to a function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, structure

I used the following program for swapping the length and width of the rectangle structure

```
typedef struct rectangle
{
  int len;
  int wid;
} rect;

void swap(int* a, int * b)
{
  int temp;
  temp= *a;     
  *a=*b;
  *b=temp;
}

int main()
{
  rect rect1;
  rect *r1;
  r1= &rect1;
  r1->len=10;
  r1->wid=5;

  cout<< "area of rect " << r1->len * r1->wid<<endl;
  swap(&r1->len,&r1->wid);

  cout<< "length=" << rect1.len<<endl;
  cout<<"width=" <<rect1.wid;
}
```

However, when i use the following:

```
swap(r1->len,r1->wid);
```

instead of:

```
swap(&r1->len,&r1->wid);
```

I am still getting correct results and I am not sure how it is working. Per my understanding I should be using `(&r1->)` to pass the address of member variable to the function. Can someone please explain?

Comment: If you omit the `&`s, it doesn't even compile...

Comment: Even if it get compiled with tons of warnings it should lead towards Segmentation fault.looking at address which is integer value.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Are you writing C or C++? AFAIK "cout" is not a C input/output command

Comment: I am using a C++ compiler.
It is getting compiled without any warnings and giving the correct result.That is why i was perplexed and asked the question.

Comment: @user2652117 I'm really curious about which compiler you're using, now...

Comment: @user2652117 are you `using namespace std;` by any chance ?

Comment: See my answer in a few seconds then :)

Comment: However you should have included that in the source code you've shared, and tagged the question with c++ and not c.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are `using namespace std;`.

In the standard c++ library exists [this version of the swap function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/swap/?kw=swap), which takes two *references* and resides in the `std` namespace.

What happens is that when you are using `&`, your function will be called. When you're not, it's the one that comes from the standard library. Indeed, with the `using` directive, you do not need to add `std::` in front of the function name. Therefore, in your case, your `swap` function exists as an overload of the one from the standard library.

Comment: That is why it is a bad practise to put the `using namespace std`.

Comment: Yes i got the point. even after removing my swap() function from the program, i am getting the same results. So as stated by you, the swap() function from the std lib is getting called here.This resolves my problem.. Thanks a lot for your response :) :)